# How to manipulate rehosted WF4 activity property sheet

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation-4, propertygrid, activitydesigner

When you click on a custom activity in a rehosted WF4 designer application, its arguments will appear on the property sheet under the category "Misc". Is it possible to manipulate this category, for example we specify some arguments to appear under the category "InArguments" and some others on "OutArguments"? How can we do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stick a `[Category("Category")]` on your property to switch which category it shows up under in the property grid.